# XML data parsing in xcode and storing it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, nsstring

i have a XML file which have 5 items(each have title and url) in it i want retrieve all of them in xcode using xml parsing and then want to store all the entries in arrays so i can use them in application. let me show you all my code.

XML File

```
<data>
<item>
<title>Eggs</title>
<link>
http://URL/ios/category.php?cat_id=14
</link>
</item>
<item>
<title>Bakery</title>
<link>
http://URL/ios/category.php?cat_id=15
</link>
</item>
<item>
<title>Bread</title>
<link>
http://URL/ios/category.php?cat_id=16
</link>
</item>
<item>
<title>Cakes, Pies Patisserie</title>
<link>
http://URL/ios/category.php?cat_id=17
</link>
</item>
<item>
<title>Specialty Breads</title>
<link>
http://URL/ios/category.php?cat_id=119
</link>
</item>
</data>
```

Here is my header file

```
#import "XMLStringFile.h"

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *rssOutputData;
    NSMutableString *nodecontent;
    NSXMLParser *xmlParserObject;
    XMLStringFile *xmlStringFileObject;
}
```

now in xcode here is my viewdidload code

```
rssOutputData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSData *xmlData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL/mycategories.xml"]];
    xmlParserObject =[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];
    [xmlParserObject setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParserObject parse];
```

here is all the parsing methods

```
#pragma mark NSXMLParser delegate
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]){
        xmlStringFileObject =[[XMLStringFile alloc]init];
    } else {
        nodecontent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [nodecontent appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
    NSLog(@"node content = %@",nodecontent);
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]){
        [rssOutputData addObject:xmlStringFileObject];
        xmlStringFileObject = nil;
    } else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]){
        xmlStringFileObject.xmltitle= nodecontent;
        nodecontent = nil;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]){
        xmlStringFileObject.xmllink= nodecontent;
        nodecontent = nil;
    }
}
```

Here is XMLStringFile.h and XMLStringFile.m

XMLStringFile.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XMLStringFile : NSObject {
    NSString *xmllink,*xmltitle;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *xmllink,*xmltitle;
@end
```

And XMLStringFile.m file

```
#import "XMLStringFile.h"
@implementation XMLStringFile
@synthesize xmllink,xmltitle;
-(void)dealloc
{
}
```

Now i want to store my both entries in two separate arrays titles and links and then i want to retrieve them from those arrays in future. I need help please do let me know how can i do this. for now xmltitle and xmllink storing retrieved data but is only nslog last entire if i use it in another function.

Comment: Why duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103948/save-retrieving-data-from-xml-parsing ?

Comment: can you give me your URL. I help you.

Comment: Yes your real http://URL/mycategories.xml

Comment: its http://cms.proxiclients.com/choithrams/mycategories.xml

Comment: You  got dictionary data then You can use of IT. am I right.

Comment: yes i need to use these retrieved entries later in a uitable view for now i just want to save all these entries in two separate arrays one for titles and one for links

Comment: See my answer that is covert your XML to Dictionary.

Comment: Now see My update answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [XMLReader](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader)

In `ViewDidLoad` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSData *xmlData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cms.proxiclients.com/choithrams/mycategories.xml"]];

    NSString *XMLString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    XMLString = [XMLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

    NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:XMLString error:nil];

    NSLog(@"== %@",dict);

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

you can get dictionary value as below.

```
NSString *linkText = [[[[dict valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"item"] valueForKey:@"link"] valueForKey:@"text"];
linkText = [linkText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Your Output is Dictionary:

[image]

Comment: i updated all the code now please view. and i download XMLReader ok i added these two file in my project so now view my code and tell me exactly what should i do

Comment: Note : Remove NSXmlParserDelegate Method from your code

Comment: by this method NSString *linkText = [[[[dict valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"item"] valueForKey:@"link"] valueForKey:@"text"]; I get data ...... my output nesscaryParsedata== (
    "8.0",
    "2.0",
    "315.0",
    "145.0"
) and i need to view in label how can i do please help me out ???